# Python get max absolute value from different lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a function that will find the maximum absolute value for each entry in three lists and combine it into one list.

Given the three lists:

```
S12 = [-3, 24,   8,  13,  24,  43,  33,  19, -14, -36, -30, -16, -21]
S23 = [13,  5, -67, -98,  37,  30,   9,  11,  -4,   2,  43,  26, -24]
S13 = [ 9, 40,  -2, -26, -25, -19, -25, -31,  36,  23,  39,  47,  29]
```

I want the code to grab the maximum absolute value, first of -3, 13 and 9 then of 24, 5 and 40 and so on.

I have the following code:

```
def maxOfThree(s1, s2, s3):
    maxOfThree = s1
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if abs(s2[i]) > abs(maxOfThree[i]):
            maxOfThree[i] = s2[i]
        elif abs(s3[i]) > abs(maxOfThree[i]):
            maxOfThree[i] = s3[i]
    return maxOfThree

maximumValueInThreeLists = maxOfThree(S12,S23,S13)
print(maximumValueInThreeLists)
```

The expected result is

```
[13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 43, 33, -31, 36, -36, 43, 47, 29]
```

but the output I get is

```
[13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 43, 33, -31, 36, -36, 43, 26, -24]
```

I cant figure out what is going wrong with my code, but some of the entries are not correct (in this case the final two, but that is just a coincedence).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in a single line:

```
S12 = [-3, 24,   8,  13,  24,  43,  33,  19, -14, -36, -30, -16, -21]
S23 = [13,  5, -67, -98,  37,  30,   9,  11,  -4,   2,  43,  26, -24]
S13 = [ 9, 40,  -2, -26, -25, -19, -25, -31,  36,  23,  39,  47,  29]

res = [max(t, key=abs) for t in zip(S12, S23, S13)]
print(res)  # -> [13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 43, 33, -31, 36, -36, 43, 47, 29]
```

This can also handle lists with different lengths due to the way `zip` is implemented. In that case, the **shortest** list will define the length of the result. If you want the code to assume zeros for the shorter lists you can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` instead. Examples of both of thoses behaviors are given below.

Assuming:

```
S12 = [-3, 24,   8,  13,  24]
S23 = [13,  5, -67, -98,  37,  30]
S13 = [ 9, 40,  -2, -26, -25, -19, -25]
```

with `zip`:

```
res = [max(t, key=abs) for t in zip(S12, S23, S13)]
print(res)  # -> [13, 40, -67, -98, 37]
```

with `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
res = [max(t, key=abs) for t in zip_longest(S12, S23, S13, fillvalue=0)]
print(res)  # -> [13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 30, -25]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with this code:

1. you use `elif` instead of an `if` in the second comparison.  hence if `s2` contains a larger value than `s1` then no comparison will ever be attempted against `s3`
2. you mutate `s1`, e.g. add `print(S12)` after running this function.  there are various ways of making a (shallow) copy, `list(s1)` or `s1[:]` are both fine choices

giving:

```
def maxOfThree(s1, s2, s3):
    maxOfThree = list(s1)
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if abs(s2[i]) > abs(maxOfThree[i]):
            maxOfThree[i] = s2[i]
        if abs(s3[i]) > abs(maxOfThree[i]):
            maxOfThree[i] = s3[i]
    return maxOfThree

maximumValueInThreeLists = maxOfThree(S12,S23,S13)
print(maximumValueInThreeLists)
```

Comment: might be easier to just swap the `elif` for `if`

Comment: That´s better. Let me change.

Comment: I've added a bit more of an explanation, hope that's OK!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
S12 = [-3, 24,   8,  13,  24,  43,  33,  19, -14, -36, -30, -16, -21]
S23 = [13,  5, -67, -98,  37,  30,   9,  11,  -4,   2,  43,  26, -24]
S13 = [ 9, 40,  -2, -26, -25, -19, -25, -31,  36,  23,  39,  47,  29]

def abs_max(s1, s2, s3):
    return [sorted(i,key=abs)[-1] for i in zip(s1, s2, s3)]
    # or even better
    # return [max(i,key=abs) for i in zip(s1, s2, s3)]
           

print(abs_max(S12, S23, S13))
```

returns

```
[13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 43, 33, -31, 36, -36, 43, 47, 29]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out = []
for i in range(len(S12)):
    out.append(max(S12[i],S23[i],S13[i], key=abs))
out

[13, 40, -67, -98, 37, 43, 33, -31, 36, -36, 43, 47, 29]
```

or in a single line

```
[max(i, key=abs) for i in zip(S12,S23,S13)]
```